# passing json data into smart suggest jquery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have purchased the jquery plugin called smart suggest and would like to pass a json array as the data rather than an array.

the current data file 'sample-data.php' looks like:

```
     array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/apple.jpg', 'description' => 'One of America\'s favorite fruits.'),
                                    'Avocado' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/avocado.jpg', 'description' => 'The avocado is a dense, evergreen tree, shedding many leaves in early spring.'),
                                    'Banana' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/banana.jpg', 'description' => 'Bananas are fast-growing herbaceous perennials arising from underground rhizomes.'),
                                    'Gooseberry' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/gooseberry.jpg', 'description' => 'Gooseberries are deciduous shrubs.'),
                                    'Grape' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/grape.jpg', 'description' => 'Grapes come in large clusters.'),
                                    'Jackfruit' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/jackfruit.jpg', 'description' => 'The jackfruit tree is handsome and stately.'),
                                    'Mango' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/mango.jpg', 'description' => 'Mango trees make handsome landscape specimens and shade trees.'),
                                    'Papaya' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/papaya.jpg', 'description' => 'The papaya is a short-lived, fast-growing, woody, large herb to 10 or 12 feet in height. It is also regarded by some as being delicious.'),
                                    'Peach' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/peach.jpg', 'description' => 'These are great in the summertime.'),
                                    'Pear' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/pear.jpg', 'description' => 'Pears are delicious fruits.'),
                                    'Pineapple' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/pineapple.jpg', 'description' => 'The pineapple plant is a herbaceous perennial, 2-1/2 to 5 ft.'),
                                    'Rose Apple' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/rose_apple.jpg', 'description' => 'The rose apple is a highly decorative evergreen large shrub.'),
                                    'Tamarind' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/tamarind.jpg', 'description' => 'The bright green, pinnate foliage is dense and feathery in appearance.'),
                                    'White Sapote' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/white_sapote.jpg', 'description' => 'The white sapote forms a medium to very large evergreen tree.'),
                                );
    $vegetables = array(
                                    'Alfalfa' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/alfalfa.jpg', 'description' => 'One cup of raw, sprouted alfalfa seeds, contains 1.32 grams of protein.'),
                                    'Artichoke' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/artichoke.jpg', 'description' => 'One medium artichoke cooked with no added salt has 3.47 grams protein.'),
                                    'Asparagus' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/asparagus.jpg', 'description' => 'Half cup (about 6 spears) cooked with no added salt contains 2.16 grams of protein.'),
                                    'Broccoli' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/broccoli.jpg', 'description' => 'Half cup of broccoli, cooked with no added salt contains 1.86 grams protein.'),
                                    'Carrots' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/carrots.jpg', 'description' => 'Half cup cooked with no added salt contains 0.59 grams protein.'),
                                    'Celery' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/celery.jpg', 'description' => 'One cup of celery, cooked, boiled, drained with no added salt has 1.25 grams protein.'),
                                    'Corn' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/corn.jpg', 'description' => 'One large ear of yellow corn, cooked with no salt contains 4.02 grams protein.'),
                                    'Green Pepper' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/green_pepper.jpg', 'description' => 'One small raw pepper contains 0.64 grams protein.'),
                                    'Mushroom' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/mushroom.jpg', 'description' => 'Half a cup of raw mushrooms contains 1.08 grams of protein.'),
                                    'Onion' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/onion.jpg', 'description' => 'One small onion cooked without salt contains 0.82 grams protein.'),
                                    'Potato' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/potato.jpg', 'description' => 'One medium baked potato without salt contains 4.33 grams of protein.'),
                                    'Spinach' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/spinach.jpg', 'description' => 'One cup of raw spinach contains 0.86 grams of protein.'),
                                    'Squash' => array('image' => 'assets/images/fruits/squash.jpg', 'description' => 'One cup of sliced summer squash, boiled with no added salt contains 1.87 grams of protein.'),
                                );
    ?>
```

this array is passed into the 'search_multiple.php' file which I would like to pass in as JSON:

```
     array(), 'vegetables' => array());
    foreach ($fruits as $name => $data)
    {
        if (stripos($name, $q) !== false)
        {
            $results['fruits'][$name] = $data;
        }
    }
    foreach ($vegetables as $name => $data)
    {
        if (stripos($name, $q) !== false)
        {
            $results['vegetables'][$name] = $data;
        }
    }

    /* Get the data into a format that Smart Suggest will read (see documentation). */
    $final_fruits = array('header' => array(), 'data' => array());
    $final_fruits['header'] = array(
                                                                            'title' => 'Fruits',                                        # Appears at the top of this category
                                                                            'num' => count($results['fruits']),         # Displayed as the total number of results.
                                                                            'limit' => 5                                                        # An arbitrary number that you want to limit the results to.
                                                                        );
    foreach ($results['fruits'] as $name => $data)
    {
        $final_fruits['data'][] = array(
                                                            'primary' => $name,                                                                                         # Title of result row
                                                            'secondary' => $data['description'],                                                        # Description below title on result row
                                                            'image' => $data['image'],                                                                          # Optional URL of 40x40px image
                                                            'onclick' => 'alert(\'You clicked on the '.$name.' fruit!\');', # JavaScript to call when this result is clicked on
                                                            'fill_text' => strtolower($name)                                                                        # Used for "auto-complete fill style" example
                                                        );
    }

    $final_vegetables = array('header' => array(), 'data' => array());
    $final_vegetables['header'] = array(
                                                                            'title' => 'Vegetables',                                        # Appears at the top of this category
                                                                            'num' => count($results['vegetables']),         # Displayed as the total number of results.
                                                                            'limit' => 5                                                                # An arbitrary number that you want to limit the results to.
                                                                        );
    foreach ($results['vegetables'] as $name => $data)
    {
        $final_vegetables['data'][] = array(
                                                            'primary' => $name,                                                                                                 # Title of result row
                                                            'secondary' => $data['description'],                                                                # Description below title on result row
                                                            'image' => $data['image'],                                                                                  # Optional URL of 40x40px image
                                                            'onclick' => 'alert(\'You clicked on the '.$name.' vegetable!\');', # JavaScript to call when this result is clicked on
                                                            'fill_text' => strtolower($name)                                                                        # Used for "auto-complete fill style" example
                                                        );
    }

    /* Output JSON */
    $final = array($final_fruits, $final_vegetables);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($final);
    die();
    ?>
```

I would like to know how to pass json data into the 'search_multiple.php' file. For example:

```
<?php
$fruits = '{
    "Apple":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/apple.jpg","description":"One of America\'s favorite fruits."},
    "Avocado":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/avocado.jpg","description":"The avocado is a dense, evergreen tree, shedding many leaves in early spring."}
    "Banana":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/banana.jpg","description":"Bananas are fast-growing herbaceous perennials arising from underground rhizomes."},
    "Gooseberry":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/gooseberry.jpg","description":"Gooseberries are deciduous shrubs."}
    "Grape":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/grape.jpg","description":"Grapes come in large clusters."},
    "Jackfruit":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/jackfruit.jpg","description":"The jackfruit tree is handsome and stately."}
    "Mango":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/mango.jpg","description":"Mango trees make handsome landscape specimens and shade trees."},
    "Papaya":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/papaya.jpg","description":"The papaya is a short-lived, fast-growing, woody, large herb to 10 or 12 feet in height. It is also regarded by some as being delicious."}
    "Peach":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/peach.jpg","description":"These are great in the summertime."},
    "Pear":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/pear.jpg","description":"Pears are delicious fruits."},
    "Pineapple":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/pineapple.jpg","description":"The pineapple plant is a herbaceous perennial, 2-1/2 to 5 ft."}
    "Rose Apple":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/rose_apple.jpg","description":"The rose apple is a highly decorative evergreen large shrub."},
    "Tamarind":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/tamarind.jpg","description":"The bright green, pinnate foliage is dense and feathery in appearance."}
    "White Sapote":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/white_sapote.jpg","description":"One cup of sliced summer squash, boiled with no added salt contains 1.87 grams of protein."},
            }';
$vegetables = '{
    "Alfalfa":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/apple.jpg","description":"One of America\'s favorite fruits."},
    "Artichoke":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/avocado.jpg","description":"The avocado is a dense, evergreen tree, shedding many leaves in early spring."}
    "Asparagus":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/banana.jpg","description":"Bananas are fast-growing herbaceous perennials arising from underground rhizomes."},
    "Broccoli":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/gooseberry.jpg","description":"Gooseberries are deciduous shrubs."}
    "Carrots":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/grape.jpg","description":"Grapes come in large clusters."},
    "Celery":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/jackfruit.jpg","description":"The jackfruit tree is handsome and stately."}
    "Corn":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/mango.jpg","description":"Mango trees make handsome landscape specimens and shade trees."},
    "Green Pepper":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/papaya.jpg","description":"The papaya is a short-lived, fast-growing, woody, large herb to 10 or 12 feet in height. It is also regarded by some as being delicious."}
    "Mushroom":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/peach.jpg","description":"These are great in the summertime."},
    "Onion":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/pear.jpg","description":"Pears are delicious fruits."},
    "Potato":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/pineapple.jpg","description":"The pineapple plant is a herbaceous perennial, 2-1/2 to 5 ft."}
    "Spinach":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/rose_apple.jpg","description":"The rose apple is a highly decorative evergreen large shrub."},
    "Squash":{"image":"assets/images/fruits/tamarind.jpg","description":"The bright green, pinnate foliage is dense and feathery in appearance."}
            }';
?>
```

Please help me!! I cannot code in PHP

Thanks

Kabeer

Comment: Since you've paid for the plugin, it should include a clear documentation. Go look for it.

Comment: I have, the documentation is actually just a copy of this website http://jamesskidmore.com/scripts/smartsuggest/, it may possibly contain the answer but I dont understand it, I have scoured it for ages

Comment: possible duplicate of [entering json data into smart suggest plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947644/entering-json-data-into-smart-suggest-plugin)

Answer (score 4):

```
$dp=mysql_select_db('test');
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8');
$sql = mysql_query('select * from users');

while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
$users[$res['username']] = array(); 
$users[$res['username']]['image'] = $res['profile_picture'];
$users[$res['username']]['email'] = $res['email'];
}
```

I've a database called test and table called users with fields(username, email, profile_picture), I'm searching for usernames to have the email and the image(look like facebook search).
This array will generate you the array you want from the database automatically, just search for user name, change in it to match your needs.